# How to draw a smooth spectrum from a discrete array of measurements at selected frequencies?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, interpolation, sensor, measurement

I have a AS7265x triad spectroscopy sensor from SparkFun ([link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15050)) which gives me measurements at 18 individual light wavelengths between 410nm and 940nm. The [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/8/3/0/AS7265x_Datasheet.pdf) says that the FWHM of each sensor is 20nm.

How can I draw a smooth spectrum given these 18 numbers?

My approach so far is to use interpolation by radial basis functions. I tried gaussian functions with FWHM=20nm but this is what I get for an artificial signal with a constant spectrum of all ones:

[image]

I experimented with other radial basis functions and found that a multiquadric function gives me the best result. It produces a flat interpolation when each measurement is equal to one. However, it looks strange at frequencies below the lowest measured frequency and above the highest one:

[image]

I fix this by requiring the lines at both ends to decrease to zero as gaussians with FWHM=20nm and amplitudes equal to the values measured at 410nm and 940nm.

Also, sometimes this interpolation shows negative values, for example, when only a single measurement is one, and all other are zeros:

[image]

I fix it by simply putting the values of the spectrum to zero where it is negative.

I tested it with a few LEDs, and I am getting spectra from them that look realistic. However, I have a feeling that my approach has too many quick fixes. My code and LED spectra are [here](https://github.com/burubaxair/spectroscopy).

Is what I am doing an acceptable way to draw a spectrum from a limited number of sensors that don't densely cover the whole range of frequencies? If not, how to do it correctly?

Comment: Great gadget!   My first question is what is your goal.  A spectrum analyzer or a color analyzer?  They are radically different creatures.  As a color analyzer your in pretty easy territory.   As a spectrum analyzer, you have to line up a requirements list/document.  In the blind concerning spectrum and no prior requirements, I would use cubic-spines for interpolation.  Be aware that there are significant improvements, knots, for the basic cubic-spline available.  Spreading the tie points to acknowledge the finite width of tie points, I would have to think about.

Comment: @rrogers Currently I want to get spectra from some fluorescent material. I would like just smooth, nicely looking spectra given the accuracy of this device. After that I want to play with this toy more and see what I can get out of it. I tried natural cubic splines with [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html) they work quite well. They just interpolated peak signals a teeny-weeny worse than multiquadric RBF, so I chose the latter.

Comment: "fluorescent " !   What a great application; at least for mineral identification!  i.e. I was looking at http://fluo.mineralogie.be/SpectraSilicates.html  Willemite & calcite section.  My previous work was gas spectral analysis in the NIR region and so isn't directly applicable but ...  Unfortunately, this comment is off-topic and I don't want the HALL-MONITORS dinging me yet again.  But for material identification you have to think well beyond just having a flat spectral response; like including the first derivative (or some such).

Comment: I still favour cubic-spline; but lacking applications/requirements I can't justify that.   In any case: Rule #1 don't mislead the user.   They really hate that; particularly if it leads them down the wrong path and hours/days of work.  Or in my case; leads them to convincing management of something that one has to attempt to retract while maintaining a shred of diginity/respect.